# Don't understand why loop isn't stopping

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm using a while loop in Python to do an action. However, the loop doesn't end when I expect it to (when teams becomes empty). This is the code:

```
while teams:
    if scores[0]<scores[1]:
        losers.append(teams[0])
        teams.remove(teams[0])
        teams.remove(teams[0])
        scores.remove(scores[0])
        scores.remove(scores[0])
    if scores[0]>scores[1]:
        losers.append(teams[1])
        teams.remove(teams[0])
        teams.remove(teams[0])
        scores.remove(scores[0])
        scores.remove(scores[0])
return losers
```

While testing the code, I put in print statements and found that the losers array has the expected result, however the loop continues after I expect it to stop, checking for scores[0] when I already deleted scores[0] on the last iteration of the loop. Why is my loop not ending?

Comment: Perhaps there are two temas with equal score?

Comment: Equal scores would mean neither if statement evaluates to true. You should include a special case for `if scores[0] == scores[1]`. Are you debugging? Have you actually checked that `scores` really *is* empty?

Comment: This is comparing NBA scores, so the game goes into continuous overtimes until one team wins. One thing I noticed when I printed the length of teams at the beginning of the loop was that it didn't print out anything when the teams' length was 12,6, or 0. (Multiples of 6) I couldn't figure out why this was, but maybe this could help debug it?

Comment: If you want us to replicate the problem, give us some hard values that you used to observe it. By the way, you can simplify your code with `teams = teams[2:]` instead of removing the first element twice.

Comment: Sure, here is the whole program so far, all you need to do is compile and run it:

http://pastebin.com/FSZF7bwg

Comment: @AdlaiAbdelrazaq please post a [mcve] if you want us to try your code.

Comment: I get an IndexError when I run your code. Why didn't you mention that?

Comment: Because the IndexError is a result of the loop not stopping. Sorry lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to change the second `if` statement to `elif`:

```
while teams:
    if scores[0]<scores[1]:
        losers.append(teams[0])
        teams.remove(teams[0])
        teams.remove(teams[0])
        scores.remove(scores[0])
        scores.remove(scores[0])
    elif scores[0]>scores[1]:
        losers.append(teams[1])
        teams.remove(teams[0])
        teams.remove(teams[0])
        scores.remove(scores[0])
        scores.remove(scores[0])
return losers
```

The problem is that when the `teams` and `scores` lists get to the last pair, and the condition in the first `if` statement is `True`, that final pair is removed and both lists become empty.

Then the second `if` condition is evaluated, but the `scores` list is now empty (courtesy of the preceding `if` matching), so an `IndexError` is raised.

Changing it to an `elif` means that the second condition will only be evaluated if the first condition is `False`. Now the loop will only process one pair of teams/scores per iteration, and the test for an empty `team` will succeed.

You could make the while loop a bit clearer with this:

```
while teams:
    if scores[0] < scores[1]:
        losers.append(teams[0])
    elif scores[0] > scores[1]:
        losers.append(teams[1])
    else:
        # this should never happen
        print('Error: drawn match detected!')
        losers.append(None)    # or simply ignore if that makes sense

    teams[:] = teams[2:]    # remove the first 2 items
    scores[:] = scores[2:]
```

Comment: @AdlaiAbdelrazaq: your prerogative, just don't blame me :)

Answer (score 0):

Double check the conditions of the loop. Loops will become infinite if a condition never becomes equal to `false`.

See the "The Infinite Loop" section of http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm.

Answer (score 0):

If the loop does not end is because `teams` never becomes empty. Your assumption "the loop doesn't end when [...] `teams` becomes empty" is incorrect and probably misguided you in your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: I agree, `teams` never becomes empty, I phrased my question wrong. I don't understand why it never becomes empty.

If you run this code: http://pastebin.com/Q1SxzFem

You will see that when the length of `teams` is 12,6,and 0, nothing is printed out. I suspect that the reason the loop isn't terminating has to do with this, but I don't understand why they aren't being printed out.